# How to encrypt ActiveMQ web console (jetty) using RSA encryption?

Tags: jetty, activemq-classic

We are using ActiveMQ v5.16.2 and it comes coupled with jetty server.
I have seen many links which point to use MD5 Hash like MD5:xxxxxx in the jetty-realm.properties file.

We need to upgrade this so that the user authentication uses RSA algorithm.

Comment: The `jetty-realm.properties` file controls the HTTP authentication / login realm.  It has nothing to do with HTTPS SSL/TLS encryption at the protocol level.  What are you looking for?  What have you tried?

Comment: I am looking update password which is encrypted using RSA. I have tried the steps mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105919/encrypting-the-web-console-password-in-activemq).
The post helps encrypt the password using MD5 which is weak encryption. We want something like a RSA, Just FYI I am new to this and basic pointers are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jetty-realm.properties` has entries that are understood by the Jetty `org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Credential` implementations.

Jetty ships with support for `CRYPT:`, `MD5:`, `OBF:`, and plain text.

Jetty supports pluggable Credential implementations via the standard `java.util.ServiceLoader` for any implementation of `org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CredentialProvider`.

[ActiveMQ does not have an implementation of CredentialProvider](https://github.com/apache/activemq/search?q=org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CredentialProvider).

If you want `RSA:` support, you'll have to write your own RSA implementation of `org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CredentialProvider` to accomplish that.